# FOR Loop array in JAVA, not working

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone point out what is wrong with my program?

I have done most of it but I can't seem to find what's wrong with it.

It doesn't ask the user for the "enter your grade" prompt for each course.

This is for an array assignment for school. Here is my code.

I am having difficulties figuring out what is wrong with the `for` loop I made specifically the `for` loop.

This program is supposed to ask the user for their courses and then the user enters their grades for that course.

If possible, please provide me hints on what I am doing wrong.

```
import java.io.*;


public class StudentMarks {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO code application logic here
    //Declare BufferedReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //declare variables
    int x=0, y=0;
    double grade=0.0;
    String course;

    //ask user how many courses they completed
    System.out.println("How many courses have you completed?");
    //obtain answer
    int completed=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    //declare array for course
    String courses[]=new String[completed];

    //ask user to enter the course names use a FOR loop for this
    for(int i=0;i<courses.length;i++)
    {
        i++;            
        System.out.println("Please enter course name " + i);
        course = br.readLine();

        for(int j=i--;j<i;j++)
        { 
            j++;
        System.out.println("What is the grade you got for " + course+ " " + j);
        //get their answer
        grade = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

        }
    }//end for loop

    //display to the user the high achievement award qualifiers:

    System.out.println("High-Ahcievement Award Qualifiers: \n");
    if(grade>93)
    {
        //output
    }
    else if(grade<70)
    {
        System.out.println("Needs Improvement:");
        //output
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does *it isn't working* mean? Do you get an error? Not the desired output?

Comment: No error, just not the desired output. I'd like to know what I am doing wrong. The output I'm getting is that it is not asking the user for the grade they got for each course. The output is only this:                             
How many courses have you completed?
4
Please enter course name 1
Course1
Please enter course name 2
Course2
Please enter course name 3
Course3
Please enter course name 4
Course4

Comment: remove i++ and j++ in the for loop block and update the code accordingly. You will see where you are failing

Comment: Is the user expected/allowed to enter more than one grade for a course?

Comment: no the user must only enter one grade for each course

Comment: Well, first thing then: if the user may enter only one grade for a course, there's certainly no need to prompt for the grade inside of a second loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `i++` use

```
System.out.println("Please enter course name " + (i+1));
```

you do not need any nested loop

```
for(int j=i--;j<i;j++)
        { 
            j++;
        System.out.println("What is the grade you got for " + course+ " " + j);
        //get their answer
        grade = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

        }
```

instead use

```
 System.out.println("What is the grade you got for " + course);
        //get their answer
        grade = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
```

HERE is the Full code if you still having trouble understanding it let me know .

```
 import java.io.*;

public class sort {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO code application logic here
    //Declare BufferedReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //declare variables
    int x=0, y=0;
    double grade=0.0;
    String course;

    //ask user how many courses they completed
    System.out.println("How many courses have you completed?");
    //obtain answer
    int completed=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    //declare array for course
    String courses[]=new String[completed];

    //ask user to enter the course names use a FOR loop for this
    for(int i=0;i<courses.length;i++)
    {            
        System.out.println("Please enter course name " + (i+1));
        course = br.readLine(); 
        System.out.println("What is the grade you got for " + course);
        //get their answer
        grade = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

    //end for loop

    //display to the user the high achievement award qualifiers:

    System.out.println("High-Ahcievement Award Qualifiers: \n");
    if(grade>93)
    {
        //output
    }
    else if(grade<70)
    {
        System.out.println("Needs Improvement:");
        //output
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped out a lot!

Comment: im new to this website, how would i mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you didnt intend to have the i++ / j++ in your for loops (first statement).
The third “parameter” of the loop head actually tells the program what to do, when it reaches the end of the loop. Therefore you increment twice each time.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner loop (with int j = i--) has a condition that is always false, and so it's body is never executed.

The line of code:

```
j = i--
```

isn't as simple as it seems and can be broken down into two lines:

```
j = i;
i = i - 1;
```

Note that j is set to the value of i, and only **after** that does i get decremented. So if j is set to i, and then i becomes i - 1, i will be one less than j. So the condition of the for loop i.e. j < i, will always be false, and so the body of the loop will never be executed.

Example:

```
i = 5;
j = i--;
```

this boils down to

```
i = 5;
j = i; //j is 5
i = i - 1; //i is 4
j < i; //5 < 4 is false, inner for loop not executed
```

Hope this helps!